# ggplot2 graphics with legends pertubated by grid.arrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my dataset:

```
> # my data --- copy and type  dd.RR <- read.table(file="clipboard")  to get it
> dd.RR 
        variance         vars
1 Op:Date:Sample 2.334140e-10
2    Date:Sample 0.000000e+00
3      Op:Sample 1.578744e-10
4        Op:Date 7.087561e-10
5         Sample 3.710173e-02
6             Op 5.429357e-01
7           Date 0.000000e+00
8         repeat 7.640778e-01
```

I plot a beautiful pie chart:

```
gg <- ggplot(dd.RR, 
        aes(x = factor(""), fill = variance, weight=vars)) + 
        geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta = "y") +
        labs(title="Reproductibilité et répétabilité") +
        scale_x_discrete("", breaks=NULL) + scale_y_continuous("", labels=NULL) 
gg
```

[image: pie chart]

But something bad happens when using `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package:

```
grid.arrange(gg,gg,ncol=2)
```

[image: pie charts side by side]

Please how to plot two ggplot2 graphics side by side when there are such legends ? (with `grid.arrange()` if possible)

Comment: use a bigger device window (pie charts have a fixed aspect ratio to remain circular; when you put two side-by-side they became really small, but the legends and titles have maintained their size and overlap each other)

Comment: @baptiste Thank you; but how to use a bigger device window please ?

Comment: `dev.new(width=10)` for example

Comment: Also consider removing one for the legends and sharing the identical legends or perhaps `facet_wrap` as it seems like `grid.arrange` is unnecessary.

Comment: @baptiste, thanks, that works with `dev.new()`. Convert your comment into an answer if you want and I accept it.

Comment: @TylerRinker Obviously my example with two identical pie charts is artificial. I have two different legends in the real example.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, could you write baptiste's answer as an answer yourself and mark it as answered to keep the question closed? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @baptiste does not convert its comment into an answer I do it:

Use a bigger device window (pie charts have a fixed aspect ratio to remain circular; when you put two side-by-side they became really small, but the legends and titles have maintained their size and overlap each other). Use for example `dev.new(width=10)`.